# Mars Anniversary

Tags: single-word-requests, latin

Does a word already exist for the anniversary of an event as measured by the orbital period of another planet? For example, (as of today on Earth) Curiosity Mars Rover has been on Mars for one Mars year, but that's 687 Earth days – nearly two Earth "anniversaries".

1. Does the term "anniversary" have an explicit "on Earth" denotation? In other words does the prefix "ann(o)-" mean *Earth* year, or can it mean "year" for any given orbital body?
2. Is the simplest way to express this "Mars anniversary", or is there a suitably understandable term?

Comment: It's a *"Martianniversity"*, of course.

Comment: The term is "Mars Year" for Mars, or Planet Year in general.

Answer (score 1):

It is known as a **return**.

Astrologers refer to the return of a planet to its sidereal position at the time of a person's birth.

So while an astrologer will refer to a *Saturn Return*, for example, as a significant event in a person's life, the term is used more widely to refer to the orbital period of a planet.

As others have said, a *Martian Year* is also widely used, especially by astronomers.

Comment: Is this usage common in astronomy, or is it confined to astrology?

Comment: But I don't think there is any phrase which would convey _Mars anniversary_ in the sense you mean it, without explanation. The concept simply does not exist in the language or in most people's minds, at least up to now.

Answer (score 1):

According to [English for Students:](http://www.english-for-students.com/anni.html) *anni*, *annu* and *enni* are the Latin roots for *year*.  As such, I believe that the word *anniversary* would refer to a year of the item preceding it.

1. Lunar Anniversary - Commemoration of the Apollo 11 Moon Landing,
   July 24, 1969
2. Anniversary Clock - A Clock that requires winding once
       a year based on a torsion pendulum

In case 1, the anniversary is used in the traditional sense.  In case 2,the anniversary is about 400 days, which would be synonymous with your measure of time regarding orbit of Mars.

Comment: Speaking of orbital bodies, *lunar* periods are especially ambiguous. Is a lunar year the orbital period of the moon around Earth, or the Earth year as measured in ... months?

Answer (score 1):

Answers:

1 - "Anniversary" does not have an explicit earth-centric origin.  It comes from Latin *annum*, which means *year*, and is thus generic.

2 - There appears to be no generally agreed-upon term that would encapsulate *anniversary* with respect to the Martian year. See the article [Timekeeping on Mars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_year) for some background. I tend to think that *Mars anniversary* fits the bill, but if you were writing a science-fiction story you might want to coin a term in order to achieve some kind of verisimilitude.  @PeterShor's "Martianniversary" in question comments is very interesting in this regard.

Some astronomical terms can be body- or body-type specific.  For example, *perigee* is the closest approach of a body to earth (*geos*), whereas *perihelion* is the closest approach of a body to the sun (*helios*).  On the other hand, *periapsis* is the generic term for closest approach of one body to another.  See [Apsis on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsis).

Incidentally, I have a suggested coinage for Martian anniversary that I just now coined:

Mars in the Greek language is *Ares*, making the term for the closest approach to Mars of the moon Deimos, for example, into *periareion*. By this token, a Martian year could be called an *Areannum*, making a Martian anniversary an *areanniversary*.

You heard it here first, folks!